# camera2 face detection call back

Tags: android, face-detection, camera2

I'm trying to use the face detector in the camera2 api. I set the preview builder to use the face detector:

```
                        previewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.STATISTICS_FACE_DETECT_MODE,
                        CameraMetadata.STATISTICS_FACE_DETECT_MODE_FULL);
                        CR = previewBuilder.build();
                        CS = session;
                        CS.setRepeatingRequest(CR, CScallback, null);
```

But I don't understand where the code hits when it detects a face? Does it return a face in the CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback? Where does it send back the info about the detected faces?

Comment: You might be using the wrong API. Which one are you using? Try the below link. It might work better for you.

https://developers.google.com/vision/face-detection-concepts

Comment: No there's an API available with camera2 it's built in. I did some research and I think it only works after you take a picture. But I need to have a face dectector while the preview is happening

Comment: You looking for something like OEMs do with their camera apps? Where a square boarders a detected face before a picture is taken?

Comment: Well square borders for testing, meaning I want to see how well it borders the face. In reality I don't want to show this to the user in the final product. I see a face object in android camera 2 which not only has the borders but the eye positions: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/params/package-summary.html The only thing is how do I access this info? And does it offer this while doing a live preview or just after a picture is taken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureResult.html

So it seems that the face data is only available after the picture is taken or in other words not while the preview is happening. When you set face detect mode on for the preview builder that means the captureresult will get the metadata when the picture is taken. I will try to find a way to do it while in preview, I think I can take snapshots of the preview and run a face detection using a background thread. I will open a separate question for that scenario.

Comment: i have the same problem with facedetection, did you solve it eventually? I try solve it during the week and now without seccess((

Comment: I reverted to camera api (the old one) instead of camera2. Sorry can't really say how to solve this

Comment: What do you think about use OpenCV? the library have a lot of properties. I asked because i decide use it, how do you think it's a good idea?

Comment: I'm not sure, I didn't really play with OpenCv that much. I used snapdragon and the camera api. https://developer.qualcomm.com/software/snapdragon-sdk-android

Answer (score 6):

I just figured out using the [Camera2 Basic sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) that it is relatively easy to get the Face array from Camera2 preview after you set the capture session correctly.

In the setUpCameraOutputs method of the Camera2 Basic sample add the following check:

```
int[] FD =characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.STATISTICS_INFO_AVAILABLE_FACE_DETECT_MODES);
int maxFD=characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.STATISTICS_INFO_MAX_FACE_COUNT);

if (FD.length>0) {
    List<Integer> fdList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int FaceD : FD
            ) {
        fdList.add(FaceD);
        Log.d(TAG, "setUpCameraOutputs: FD type:" + Integer.toString(FaceD));
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "setUpCameraOutputs: FD count" + Integer.toString(maxFD));

    if (maxFD > 0) {
        mFaceDetectSupported = true;
        mFaceDetectMode = Collections.max(fdList);
    }
}
```

Then in the createCameraPreviewSession() method that creates the capture session add the following call for face detection method:

```
@Override
public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
    // The camera is already closed
    if (null == mCameraDevice) {
        return;
    }
    // When the session is ready, we start displaying the preview. ...
    // Flash is automatically enabled when necessary.
    setAutoFlash(mPreviewRequestBuilder);

    //>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>HERE>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                                   
    //Face detection setup
    setFaceDetect(mPreviewRequestBuilder,mFaceDetectMode);...
```

Where the setFaceDetect(mPreviewRequestBuilder,mFaceDetectMode); code can be like this:

```
private void setFaceDetect(CaptureRequest.Builder requestBuilder , int faceDetectMode){
    if (mFaceDetectSupported){
        requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.STATISTICS_FACE_DETECT_MODE,faceDetectMode);
    }

}
```

Face detection can be done in CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback by adding just few lines of code:

```
 private CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback mCaptureCallback
        = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

private void process(CaptureResult result) {
    switch (mState) {
        case STATE_PREVIEW: {
            // We have nothing to do when the camera preview is working normally.
            //But we can for example detect faces 
            Face face[]=result.get(CaptureResult.STATISTICS_FACES);
            if (face.length>0 ){
                Log.d(TAG, "face detected " + Integer.toString(face.length));
                takePicture();
            }

            break;
        }
```

I tested this change of the code and it works (I capture selfie once my face is detected... You can look into  more options of the Face class here:
[Face](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/params/Face.html)

Comment: Thanks for this, is working great, but I needed to add a null check for face. if (face != null && face.length>0) works perfectly fine